# How to create unboxed mutable array instance

Tags: haskell, stuarray, marray

let's say I've got the following type :

`data MyType = Constructor0 | Constructor1 | Constructor2
            deriving (Eq,Show,Enum)`

Is there a way to create one of such instances :

`MArray (STUArray s) MyType (ST s)
MArray IOUarray MyType IO`

For the moment I store everything as Word8 and I make conversion with (wrapped) fromEnum/toEnum, but it doesn't feel right. I need strictness and unboxing because I'm using a large data structure (>1.2Go) in memory, and I can't load it lazily. If I don't find any solution I'm going to re-implement everything in C++, which I prefer to avoid for my current project.

I've asked the question on #haskell but I didn't get a response, maybe it was not the good time of the day to ask.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest implementation I could think of: just wrap `STUArray`/`IOUArray` operations with `fromEnum`/`toEnum`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

module UnpackedEnumArray (STUEArray, IOUEArray) where

import Control.Monad.ST
import Data.Array.Base
import Data.Array.IO
import Data.Array.ST

data STUEArray s i e = STUEArray { fromSTUEArray :: STUArray s i Int }
instance (Enum e) => MArray (STUEArray s) e (ST s) where
    getBounds = getBounds . fromSTUEArray
    getNumElements = getNumElements . fromSTUEArray
    newArray is = fmap STUEArray . newArray is . fromEnum
    newArray_ = fmap STUEArray . newArray_
    unsafeRead (STUEArray a) = fmap toEnum . unsafeRead a
    unsafeWrite (STUEArray a) i = unsafeWrite a i . fromEnum

data IOUEArray i e = IOUEArray { fromIOUEArray :: IOUArray i Int }
instance (Enum e) => MArray IOUEArray e IO where
    getBounds = getBounds . fromIOUEArray
    getNumElements = getNumElements . fromIOUEArray
    newArray is = fmap IOUEArray . newArray is . fromEnum
    newArray_ = fmap IOUEArray . newArray_
    unsafeRead (IOUEArray a) = fmap toEnum . unsafeRead a
    unsafeWrite (IOUEArray a) i = unsafeWrite a i . fromEnum
```

Now you can

```
import UnpackedEnumArray
main = do
    a <- newArray (0,9) Constructor0 :: IO (IOUEArray Int MyType)
    getAssocs a >>= print
```

Likewise, `IArray` instances could be trivially written as well.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't thought about creating a new type for this, it's a nice way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Making an instance for `MArray IOUarray MyType IO` should be possible. Take a look at the source for the instance declaration for `MArray IOUarray Bool IO`.

Since Bool is an instance of both `Enum` and `Bounded` (and not much else) they probably use functions from those classes when making the instance.

You might have to derive `Bounded` but that is probably not an issue since unboxed arrays can contain fixed size elements only.

**Edit:**

In [this](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Arrays#Unboxed_arrays) article one can read

> You can even implement unboxed arrays yourself for other simple types, including enumerations.